# Layoutproblem: Fontdesign in header (minipage)

Tags: fonts, header-footer, titles

I tried to solve a layout-header-design with minipage. But within the minipage I got several problems:

- different font sizes
- linebreaks, leftalign
- more linespread for a single word

  ```
  \documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}

  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}              
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}      

  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}

  \lhead{Senat}
  \rhead{Sitzungsprotokoll, Seite \thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

  \begin{document}

      \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} 
      \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{logo.png}
      \end{minipage}
      \hfill
      \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
      TEXT?
      \end{minipage}

  \vspace{2cm}    

  \begin{center}
  \Huge \textbf{Sitzungsprotokoll vom \today}
  \end{center}

  \end{document}
  ```

How to achieve this (from Word):

[image]

So what I have so far is (LaTEX):

[image]

Comment: Using `fancyhdr` along with KOMA-script is discouraged, better to use `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Is that seen the header? With logo and adress? To be applied to every single page?

Comment: No, that's just "Lorem ipsum"  but in exactly the style I like to achieve. And no, this should be just placed on the first page. That's why, I thought minipage should do it.

Comment: Ah, It is the font and its appearance you want to change?

Comment: Yes this is correct :) my first aim is the font design.

Comment: That is a sans serif font, which one exactely i cannot say.

Comment: `\rhead{\sffamily Sitzungsprotokoll, Seite \thepage}` perhaps?

Comment: btw: Font design is a completely different thing, we are just choosing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to the  sans-serif font using `\sffamily`. In the example below, i have choosen TeX Gyre Adventor (available through `tgadventor`), mainly because it was the first coming to mind. Using `\raggedright`, we get text that is flushed to the left.

[image: macScrartclProtokoll]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,a4paper,headlines=1,headinclude=true,headsepline,footsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}      

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tgadventor}% choosing a font
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ihead{Senat}
\ohead{Sitzungsprotokoll, Seite \thepage}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \sffamily\raggedright
    {\Huge FAKULTÄTSRAT\par}
    der zahnmedizinischenFakultät\\
    Georg August\\
    STUDENT COUNCIL\\
    some more nonmatching text\\
    \rule[.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{.4pt}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}    

\begin{center}
    \Huge \textbf{Sitzungsprotokoll vom \today}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

Using XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX), we don't have to care about the input encoding anymore, utf8 seems to be used anyway. It also gives a nice interface to declare font properties. Following, an Arial clone and a Times clone, just like ...

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,a4paper,headlines=1,headinclude=true,headsepline,footsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}      
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ihead{Senat}
\ohead{Sitzungsprotokoll, Seite \thepage}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \sffamily\raggedright
    {\Huge\addfontfeature{ LetterSpace=20 } FAKULTÄTSRAT\par}
    der zahnmedizinischen Fakultät\\
    Georg August\\
    STUDENT COUNCIL\\
    some more nonmatching text\par
    \rule[.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{.4pt}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}    

\begin{center}
    \Huge \textbf{Sitzungsprotokoll vom \today}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: macScrartclProtokoll]

Comment: Thank you, this looks very good. I also found `microtype` which provides the necessary space between letters for the initial word  `\textls{<letterspaced text>}`

Comment: @Mac Please see the update.

Comment: +1 In your first example there is a space missing between `zahnmedizinischenFakultät`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I noticed that. Should i really change it or just leave it? One simple typo doesn't really make the answer better or worse.

Comment: @Johannes_B True, it doesn't reduce the functionality it just looks odd.